# using socket.shutdown(1) is preventing web server from sending responses

Tags: python, sockets

I'm making a proxy which sits between the browser and the web. There's a snippet of code I can't seem to get to work.

```
#send request to web server
web_client.send(request)
#signal client is done with sending
web_client.shutdown(1)
```

If I use shutdown(1), the proxy has a *great* improvement in performance and speed. 
However, some web servers do not send responses if I use shutdown. Console output:

```
request sent to host wix.com
got response packet of len 0
got response packet of len 0
breaking loop
```

and the browser displays

```
The connection was reset
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
```

However, if I remove shutdown(1), there are no problems of sort. Console output:

```
got response packet of len 1388
got response packet of len 1388
got response packet of len 1388
got response packet of len 989
got response packet of len 0
got response packet of len 0
breaking loop
```

and the browser normally displays the website.
Why is this happening? This is only happening on certain hosts.

Comment: Check if the keep-alive parameter is being set for hosts where it's failing.

Comment: I've checked, it's irrelevant.

Comment: By the way I've found a workaround setting a use_shut boolean parameter that defaults to true. If the program gets this error, it sends the request again setting use_shut to false and shutdown(1) is not used. It seems to work,but it's quite awful.

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown

> Depending on the platform, shutting down one half of the connection
>   can also close the opposite half (e.g. on Mac OS X, shutdown(SHUT_WR)
>   does not allow further reads on the other end of the connection)

This may not be the problem because you say that only *some* web servers are affected, but is your proxy running on Mac OS X?

Comment: No, it's on Linux. I suppose it's due to the web server though, since I don't have this problem with most web hosts.

Answer (score 0):

TCP/IP stack will do graceful connection close only if there is no pending data to be sent on the socket. send completion indicates only the data is pushed into the kernel buffer & ready for sending. Here, shutdown is invoked immediately after send while there is some send data pending in the TCP stack. So TCP stack sends reset to the other end as it decides the application doesn't wish to complete sending the process. To do a graceful connection close, invoke select on the socket & wait for socket to be writable which means all the data is pushed out the stack. Then invoke shutdown & close the socket.